# How to make my barchart more beautiful

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Testbench: Bitzähler (Speicher)},
    xlabel={Reduktionsarten},
    ylabel={Fehlerstellen},
    major x tick style=transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=25pt,
    x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=center},
    symbolic x coords={ALL, WRITE, READ},
    ymax=2500,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={1,10,100,1000,10000},
    legend pos= outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log basis y={10},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]

%NONE
\addplot[fill=red!60] coordinates { 
  (ALL,1408)[\textcolor{red!60}{1408}]
  (WRITE,352)[\textcolor{red!60}{352}]
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{red!60}{1056}]
};

%MODIFIER
\addplot[fill=blue!60] coordinates {
  (ALL,1408)[\textcolor{blue!60}{1408}]
  (WRITE,352)[\textcolor{blue!60}{352}]
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{blue!60}{1056}]
};

\addplot[fill=yellow!60] coordinates {
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{yellow!60}{1056}]};

\addplot[fill=green!60] coordinates {
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{green!60}{1056}]};

  \legend{NONE, MODIFIKATOR, ÄQUIVALENZKLASSE, ÄQUI + MODI}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I align my `ALL` and `WRITE` bars to the middle? I believe it's already aligned, but the other 2 bars are 0 here. But they need to be over the `WRITE` and `ALL` points. 
How can I give the `ALL`, `WRITE` and `READ` text more space between them and the x-axis?
The colors are ugly too. :( Something like the following picture is more beautiful. 
[image]
How do I do this? How can I make my graphs more beautiful after all?

Sorry for the many questions. I am a little bit in a hurry, because I have to turn in my thesis tomorrow. I hope you guys understand!
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: For  colours, you may use  the colours-by-name options of `xolor` (`dvipsnames`, `x11names` and `svgnames`) and make your choice. Furthermore these colours can be mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not how to respond to "the colors are ugly" since, after all, you chose these colors. However, it is easy enough to shift the `xtick labels` around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Testbench: Bitzähler (Speicher)},
    xlabel={Reduktionsarten},
    ylabel={Fehlerstellen},
    major x tick style=transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=25pt,
    x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=center},
    symbolic x coords={ALL, WRITE, READ},
    xticklabel style={yshift=-2mm,xshift={ifthenelse(\ticknum==2,0,-26)}}, 
    ymax=2500,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={1,10,100,1000,10000},
    legend pos= outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log basis y={10},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]
%NONE
\addplot[fill=red!60] coordinates { 
  (ALL,1408)[\textcolor{red!60}{1408}]
  (WRITE,352)[\textcolor{red!60}{352}]
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{red!60}{1056}]
};

%MODIFIER
\addplot[fill=blue!60] coordinates {
  (ALL,1408)[\textcolor{blue!60}{1408}]
  (WRITE,352)[\textcolor{blue!60}{352}]
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{blue!60}{1056}]
};

\addplot[fill=yellow!60] coordinates {
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{yellow!60}{1056}]};

\addplot[fill=green!60] coordinates {
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{green!60}{1056}]};

\legend{NONE, MODIFIKATOR, ÄQUIVALENZKLASSE, ÄQUI + MODI}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After clarification what you meant by your statement on the colors, I'd suggest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Testbench: Bitzähler (Speicher)},
    xlabel={Reduktionsarten},
    ylabel={Fehlerstellen},
    major x tick style=transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=25pt,
    x tick label style={rotate=0, anchor=center},
    symbolic x coords={ALL, WRITE, READ},
    xticklabel style={yshift=-2mm,xshift={ifthenelse(\ticknum==2,0,-26)}}, 
    ymax=2500,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={1,10,100,1000,10000},
    legend pos= outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log basis y={10},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]
%NONE
\addplot[draw=red,thick,fill=red,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates { 
  (ALL,1408)[\textcolor{red!60}{1408}]
  (WRITE,352)[\textcolor{red!60}{352}]
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{red!60}{1056}]
};

%MODIFIER
\addplot[draw=blue,thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (ALL,1408)[\textcolor{blue!60}{1408}]
  (WRITE,352)[\textcolor{blue!60}{352}]
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{blue!60}{1056}]
};

\addplot[draw=orange,thick,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{yellow!60}{1056}]};

\addplot[draw=green!60!black,thick,fill=green!60!black,fill opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (READ,1056)[\textcolor{green!60}{1056}]};

\legend{NONE, MODIFIKATOR, ÄQUIVALENZKLASSE, ÄQUI + MODI}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Notice that for some reason my compiler suppresses the umlaute. I believe you won't have this issue. However, I do not know how to make the umlaute appear. I just compile with `xelatex`.)

Comment: As usual, very nice @marmot. Thank you!
To the colors: That was a bad choice of words. I mean the display of the bars is not very nice. How do i do this slightly transparent style with firm edges, like in my example?

Comment: @AndiYo I'd replace `fill=red!60` by `draw=red,thick,fill=red,fill opacity=0.6` and similarly for the other colors. That way you see the dashed line shining through the interiors of the bars.